# How to create an embossed button in objective c programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, user-interface

How can I create a styled button like the one showed below? I know Facebook is using the [Three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20) framework to generate the buttons programmatically. I think it's overwhelming.

I'm rather new developer of ios so I wonder what is the most common way to create buttons like this? (except for using images).

[image: Facebook iPhone App]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple way to create is

1. Create UIButton programmatically
2. Use gradient to create that background effect.

To create gradient for back ground use:  CAGradientLayer, CAGradientLayer.frame and CAGradientLayer.color

Assign gradient to the button use: AddSublayer, CornerRadius, and MasksToBounds on UIButton.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use Jess Martin's CoolButton that draws glassy iOS style buttons, all using CoreGraphics and no images - https://github.com/jessmartin/CoolButtons
2. Jeff Lamarche's iPhone Gradient buttons - http://code.google.com/p/iphonegradientbuttons/

Look at related questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

When I want a button like that I tend to just create it in software such as Photoshop. Then you can just set a `UIButton` to have a custom style and setup the image as the button background.

Here is a nice [tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/building-buttons-photoshop-1/) on creating button in photoshop. Hope this helps.